# Is there activity ID in Android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm writing an Android app and I've got a problem. I make few alarms in my app, each of them is connected another activity. I'd like to know if is there possibility to identify each of these activity, because user can delete alarm(from database) and activity will be still running.

Now the app is running fine for one alarm, but if I set for example three alarms then only the last one is working fine.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Activities hashCode()... its unique.