# Android: userId - GET PHP alternative?

Tags: android

so I have an app where users have accounts/profiles, when say you type name and surname in search it would bring to activity called ProfileViewer and display that users details.

In PHP I would have link like:
`<a href="http://website.com/profile.php?id=xxx">John Sample</a>`

So when user clicks on that - it would go to PHP page called profile.php and load data from MySQL database WHERE userid=xxx.

So what's the alternative in Android? I am a bit lost, what are some of my options on how to identify which userID is Activity loading?

Could I use `putExtra("userId", xxx)` and then use `getExtra()`?

In other words: How can I make one activity act like page which accepts 1 param and then uses it on opening?

Comment: Feel free to remove the formatting on the link (not sure if you wanted it to show as a link or code, but code makes sense to me). For inline code, you can use backticks (the thing to the left of the 1)

Comment: @Jakar yes thank you, I didn't realize it will auto convert it into link.

Comment: @arleitiss `how to identify which userID is Activity loading?` Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102967/unique-id-of-an-android-activity) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369448/is-there-activity-id-in-android-app) ?

Comment: @Outofmemory Not quite, that seems to be a resource/string assigned by OS itself, while in my case I am looking for more like: Have array of id's/numbers, create a list of buttons or listview with onclickclistener, then based on which button/listview item is clicked = it will open SAME activity but with that id.

Comment: @arleitiss I think you would have to do that yourself. Please see [the official doc](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intent extras are generally the way to go in these cases.

From the first activity you would:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("userId", 1);
startActivity(intent);
```

And you then retrive the information in the second activity like this:

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("userId");
```

Comment: Say if I have an array of id's/numbers, say 100 numbers, can I use for loop to create 100 buttons and assign onClickListener for each of them with different putExtra (1 loop iteration = 1 unique id with profile). Or would that be heavy load on app? Would ListView work better for this case?

Comment: @arleitiss, you could use one `onClickListener` and assign it to each button. Then you could do `button.setTag(userId)` on each button, then in the onclicklistener, use `userId = button.getTag()`; But a `ListView` would probably be the way to go. Using 100 buttons could create rendering/lag problems and I *think* (but am not sure) Android has extra memory management tweaks for `ListView`s which you wouldn't get the benefit of with a bunch of `Button`s in a `ScrollView`. And you can neatly tie data (such as a `Cursor`) to a `ListView`.

Comment: @Jakar Quick question: Does ListView items support setTag() so I can identify items individually rather than getting selectedItemPosition and then calculating/getting specific id that was assigned to that item?

Comment: @arleitiss, you could set the tag on the view you are returning in the `getView()` method of your list adapter, but that would prevent you from using the view holder pattern (http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) which greatly improves scrolling performance. So I would recommend using its position or overriding the `getItemId()` method in the adapter to return an id based on a position.